# Login with cassandra user at container startup

Tags: docker, cassandra

I have a cassandra container started on which I overwrite the cassandra.yaml file with the updated property:

```
authenticator: PasswordAuthenticator
```

instead

```
authenticator: AllowAllAuthenticator
```

This will allow me to create new superuser on the new instance.

Now, after this instance, I create a new image named cassandra-new which has the new cassandra.yaml file. So when I start it, it will allow me to create a new role for may cassandra db.

The problem is that I must manually go inside the instance:

```
docker exec -it cassandra-new /bin/bash
```

Then I have to manually type in:

```
cqlsh -u cassandra -p cassandra
```

And then I can write my script:

```
CREATE ROLE IF NOT EXISTS some WITH SUPERUSER = true AND LOGIN = true AND PASSWORD = 'supersome';
LIST ROLES;
```

How can I do this automatically without ENTRYPOINT?(because I already tried it for 2 days now and I got tired of it - not working)
(Please provide code instead of words because I am newby.)

Dockerfile is created by shell script:

```
if [[ ! -e Dockerfile ]]; then
    touch Dockerfile
    cat >> Dockerfile << EOF
    FROM cassandra:latest
    COPY cassandra.yaml cassandra:etc/cassandra/cassandra.yaml
EOF
fi
```

docker-entrypoint.sh was not changed - so it is the same as the default one provided by cassandra latest image.

Comment: Can you provide your current `dockerfile` and `docker-entrypoint` if any.

Answer (score 2):

Unless cassandra docker image developers support special environment variables or some init scripts that are automatically run as part of their entrypoint (mysql for example has a folder where you mount .sql, .sh or .gz files and it will execute them accordingly), then you do require a custom entrypoint or just have to do this manually...

One way to do it would be a simple script that starts the cassandra container and runs those commands, but depending on your environment that can be either shell or batch script so this is quite a custom solution.

Since the cassandra entrypoint is probably what is starting the service and doing the init process the only way to actually manage this would be a custom entrypoint.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this gist](https://gist.github.com/derlin/0d4c98f7787140805793d6268dae8440) that shows how to create a cassandra docker image that can execute any bash or cql scripts upon startup.

Following this gist, you can simply add a cql script inside the container e.g. `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/create_roles.cql` with the following content:

```
CREATE ROLE IF NOT EXISTS some WITH SUPERUSER = true AND LOGIN = true AND PASSWORD = 'supersome';
LIST ROLES;
```

It will be executed automatically on startup.